# ajax should post current index of partial view loaded by loop

Tags: ajax, post, foreach, partial-views

On my page I have a carousel of images. Each image tile is a partial view comprised of the image and product data.  So the carousel is actually full of partial views which is loaded from a parent partial view via loop...

when I select an image to add to cart I use ajax to post to the controller and this works.

The problem is the ajax script is loading once for every product in the model i.e. for ever iteration of the for loop and for each product in the model...the script loads so the result is every product loads into the cart...here is some code

parent partial

```
    foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <div id="view-option">
        @Html.Partial("../Product/_ProductTitleHome", p)
    </div>
}
```

child partial has an Form with multiple inputs

```
                    <form id="addToCartForm" method="post" action="/Product/AddToCart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ProductId" value="Model.ProductId" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="Sku" value="Model.Sku" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="Quantity" value="Model.MinQuantity" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="bundleItemsIds" value="Model.BundleItemsIds" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="SeoPageName" value="Model.SeoPageName" />
                     <button class="btn-card btn-add-cart red hvr-shadow" id="btn-addtocart-short" data-value="Model.ProductId"><i class="zf-cart"></i>ButtonAddToCart</button>
                    }
                </form>
```

and the ajax call is this

`$('#btn-addtocart-short').click(function (e) {
        event.currentTarget();
        //var dataObj = $('#addToCartForm').serialize();
        var dataObj = {
            ProductId: '@Model.ProductId',
            Sku: '@Model.Sku',
            Quantity: '@Model.MinQuantity',
            bundleItemsIds: '@Model.BundleItemsIds',
            SeoPageName: '@Model.SeoPageName'
        }
        if (dataObj != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Product/AddToCart',
                type: "POST",
                data: dataObj,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('this worked');
                },
            });
        }
    });`

so again...if I click on an image tile to add it to the cart the ajax execute as many time as there are products in the model...and again this is because this partial is loaded via loop...

So I need to find a way to have ajax only execute for the item(the index of the item) that was clicked.

Please help

Comment: When jquery builds the dataObj it only seems to grab the data from the first partial view regardless of which element is clicked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was the partial view.  Each image was in a partial view and for all images loaded into the slider...the partial view loaded and the Ajax executed everytime...so the solution was to pull the code out of the partial view and go up one level to the parent view...insert the code and the problem was solved.  All the images loaded and the Ajax only fired once because the parent view only loaded once.